# CSS - table fixed height/width with scrollable content in cells

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to create a full-page calendar. It should take 100% width and height excluding navbar on the top.

I want to put some content inside and make it scrollable if it does not fit the box. The cells should not resize!

Finally with the help of internet I made something, but fixed sizes do not work.

Also the day should be in the left top corner, but it seems floating near the middle of the box.

```
table.cal_month_calendar td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #444;
  text-align: left;
}
table.cal_month_calendar td span.date {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
table.cal_month_calendar td div.events {
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 7em;
}
```

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/n2jgrtat/

I know that there were a lot of similar questions, but I failed to search exactly this case.